# Operar con sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

estoy intentando crear 2 sliders que al desplazarlos vayan operando con los valores del momento y me muestre a su vez el resultado. Pongo el código para mostrar el caso:

```
    <div id="slider_1" class="slider"></div><input id="slider_1_val
    </input> EUROS
    <div id="slider_2" class= "slider"></div> 
    <input type="text" min="30" max="90"  step="30"></input> DIAS
    Resultado:<input id="amount"></input>   



var weightSliderValue = 0;
var exerciseSliderValue = 0; 

function changeValue(){
    var currentSliderValue = (weightSliderValue -
    (weightSliderValue * exerciseSliderValue));

    $( "#slider_1_val" ).val( weightSliderValue );
    $( "#slider_2_val" ).val( exerciseSliderValue );  
    $( "#amount" ).val( currentSliderValue );


}

$( "#slider_1" ).slider({ 
  min: 1000,
  max: 5000,
  step: 100,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
      weightSliderValue = ui.value;
      changeValue();
  }
});

$( "#slider_2" ).slider({ 
  min: 0.03,
  max: 0.09,
  step: 0.03,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {         
      exerciseSliderValue = ui.value;
      changeValue();
  }
});
```

El resultado me devuelve lo que quiero, pero el problema que tengo es que para los valores del segundo slider quiero que a medida que muevo el slider se me muestren otros valores diferentes a los que uso para operar (en este caso 0.03 - 0.06 - 0.09 respectivamente) y no sé cómo hacerlo

Comment: Ahí edite la respuesta, pegale una mirada aver si ahora si es lo que necesitas!

Answer (score 1):

Si no interprete mal tu problema, se da por lo siguiente;

vos en la siguiente linea:

```
$("#slider_2_val").val( exerciseSliderValue );
```

Asignas el `.val()` a un objeto de `id="slider_2_val"`

Y dentro de tu html, no existe tal id.

Bastaría con asignarle el `id` a cualquiera de tus `input` y verías el resultado que esperas

```
<input type="text" min="30" max="90"  step="30" id="slider_2_val">DIAS
```

Espero ese sea tu problema, sino intentá aclararlo un poco más!

Saludos

**EDIT**

Para lograr lo que necesitas,bastaría con realizar el cálculo o el condicional necesario para llegar al dato que queres mostrar, por ejemplo, podrías usar un switch;

```
  $( "#slider_2" ).slider({ 
  min: 0.03,
  max: 0.09,
  step: 0.03,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {         

    switch(ui.value)
    {
      case 0.03: exerciseSliderValue = 30; break;
      case 0.06: exerciseSliderValue = 60; break;
      case 0.09: exerciseSliderValue = 90; break;
      default: exerciseSliderValue = 0; break;
    }


    changeValue();
  }
```

En este caso, cuando el resultado sea `0.03`, `exerciseSliderValue` valdrá `30`, osea que en tu `input` mostrarías `30`

Otra opción es definirlo mediante un cálculo, por ejemplo

```
  $( "#slider_2" ).slider({ 
  min: 0.03,
  max: 0.09,
  step: 0.03,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {         

   exerciseSliderValue = ui.value*1000;

    changeValue();
  }
  }); </script>
```

Aquí llegarías al mismo resultado que en el ejemplo de arriba, pero en base a tu problema, será el método que elijas para definir el valor, como existen estos 2 ejemplos, existirán también miles mas!

Espero que ahora si tu duda haya quedado clara!

Comment: El problema no es ese, si hiciera lo que me estás recomendando, me aparecería en el input los valores 0.03  - 0.06   y 0.09  que son los que genero en la función:         

        $( "#slider_2" ).slider({ 
          min: 0.03,
          max: 0.09,
          step: 0.03,
          slide: function( event, ui ) {         
          exerciseSliderValue = ui.value;
           changeValue();
            }
          });


Pero en mi caso lo que necesito, es que en ese input me aparezcan otros valores diferentes por ejemplo 50  60  y 70

Comment: @miaweb ahí edité la respuesta para que puedas hacer lo que necesitas!